# Finding first element of an array containing "-"

Tags: c#

I have an array that could contain values like the following:

array[0] = "M6"

array[1] = "-"

array[2] = "0138"

array[3] = "XY"

or

array[0] = "K7"

array[1] = "(RM"

array[2] = "-"

array[3] = "1212"

array[4] = ")"

Is there a way that I can find the first element in the array that contains "-"?

Perhaps something like:

`var elementWithMinus = array.Contains("-");`

I know that `Contains` returns a bool if the value was found in the collection.  I was just wondering if there was a way to know which element contains the value.

For clarity, I want to be able to determine the index of the array contains the value.  So, for the first example, the index I want returned would be `1` because array[1] contains "-".

Comment: You want to find the element or the index of the element?

Comment: The index of the element that contains the value. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ?

```
         Array.IndexOf(array, "-");
```

Comment: Ack!  I thought I could only use `IndexOf` on strings, not collections.  Thanks!

Comment: IndexOf is just a static method on Array, but as its static you wont find it in intellisense unless you're looking for it. 

IndexOf on a string *is* different, although it shares the name.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.